# htaccess querystring wildcard matching

Tags: .htaccess

Help again please...

My htaccess file is like...

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^search_results.asp$ /search/?s=%1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

This works with:
    http://dev.domain.com/search_results.asp?search=tile

But I also need it to work if there is anything else after "search=" - e.g.
    http://dev.domain.com/search_results.asp?search=tile&page=1&sortby=a

Specifically, I need to ignore anything else...

The number of additional parameters is variable, so can I use wildcards for this?

Comment: I think the whole query string is passed using that rewrite rule so the other parameters should be available already. Did you already try to fetch the 'sortby' parameter for example?

Comment: I need to ignore anything else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} search=(.*?)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^search_results\.asp$ /search/?s=%1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: It still adds the rest of the querystring, but I don't think I can do anything about that. Thanks!